# How to get the name of the triggered event?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, shipping-methods

How to self check what event i am using,  my event : 
`<checkout_cart_product_add_after>` 
how to print, i tried :

```
$event = $observer->getEvent()->getName(); 
Mage::log($event, null, 'logfile.log');
```

its not printing

Comment: You should be more specific in your question, so people can answer it... If you are using a custom module you'd be listening to a specific event, defined in your module config.xml file, and there should be the specific event name, if that's what you are asking

Comment: @RaulSanchez Pls check with my updated post

Comment: I hope now you peoples understand my post : @ Mohit Kumar Arora, Rohan Hapani, Jai, Manashvi Birla, Aasim Goriya

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the `sales_quote_save_after` event, then use the quote to get the shipping rates. The following code can be used to get the list of shipping rates.

```
$quote->getShippingAddress()->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
```

Comment: I need shipping methods, how to alter with your code

Comment: create sales_quote_save_after observer

Comment: I just try to list what are all the shipping methods available using mage::log, i am getting error  https://paste.ofcode.org/32Z2DhpEGzVMkqEuxeJLuZr

Comment: Try This $observer->getShippingAddress()->getGroupedAllShippingRates();

Comment: logfile.log not created in var/log location, my code -> https://paste.ofcode.org/DdR3aizM5cP5dbn6ghYdpf

Comment: wait let me check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97372/discussion-between-zus-and-rk-rathod).

Comment: Before order what event i need to use, for my condition i need shipping method how can i get before place an order? @Rk